# Angular $locationChangeStart prevent reload & leave page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi read a lots of posts about prevent relaod and leave page and I try to implement this solution on my SPA apps (angular 1.6) but it does't work

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            if (true) {
                var answer = confirm("Test");
                if (!answer) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }    
        });
```

this part of code is executed when I enter on my page and not when I try to go out. Also I've try to inject $window and add two event but doesn't work

```
$window.onunload = function(event){
            var answer = confirm("onunload");
            if (!answer) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }


        $window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
            var answer = confirm("onbeforeunload");
            if (!answer) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.run(function($window){
    var window = angular.element($window);
    windowElement.on('onbeforeunload', function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    }) 
})
```

for more on [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: it's not working. I try to intercept event on chrome but never rise. Any idea?